# Parsing lsf.str output in R

Tags: r, parsing, package, documentation

The `lsf.str` function return the function name and description, e.g., as follows:

```
func_names <- lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("dplyr"), pattern="count")
func_names
```

The output for the above code is

```
add_count : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = deprecated())  
add_count.data.frame : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = deprecated())  
add_count.default : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = deprecated())  
add_count_ : function (x, vars, wt = NULL, sort = FALSE)  
add_count_impl : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = deprecated(), error_call = caller_env())  
count : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL)  
count.data.frame : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = group_by_drop_default(x))  
count_ : function (x, vars, wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, .drop = group_by_drop_default(x))  
count_regroups : function (code)
```

Now when I run `func_names[1]`
The output is `[1] "add_count"`.

I was expecting to get the full line (name and description) as shown in the output above instead of just the name. What is it that I am missing here?

Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsf.str` produces an object of class `ls_str`. This object does not itself contain the information you see when you type `func_names` into the console. Instead, it contains the names of the objects and information about where to find them. Its print method then looks them up whenever you want to display the object.

Unfortunately, subsetting removes the attributes of this object, so it reverts to a plain character vector. If you want the output in exactly the same format, you would need to do something like:

```r
`attributes<-`(func_names[1], attributes(func_names))
#> add_count : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = deprecated())
```

If you just want `func_names` to contain all the information as a character string, you could use `capture.output`:

```r
func_names <- capture.output(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("dplyr"), pattern = "count"))
func_names[1]
#> [1] "add_count : function (x, ..., wt = NULL, sort = FALSE, name = NULL, .drop = deprecated())  "
```

Then `cat(func_names[1])` will be in the same format as the original.

Comment: Thanks Allan, that's exactly what I was looking for. On changing the command to func_names <- capture.output(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("dplyr"), pattern = "group_by_")), I find that the entry for group_by_prepare (last one) is split into two elements. Is there a way to undo this i.e. have one vector for each function.

Comment: It likely got split because it was too wide to fit, and you're seeing it wrapped to the next line.  You could set `options(width=10000)` and they'd be very unlikely to wrap.  (I have mine set to `width=126` and none of the lines in your example wrapped.)  Change it back afterwards....